# Single vertex still has weight on it despite not showing anything in weight paint mode?

Tags: mesh, vertices, weight-painting, vertex-weights, vertex-paint-mode

So when I move certain bones theres always a single vertex that moves and no matter how much I try to subtract paint it does nothing.

[image]

[image]

Not sure how to fix this or why it even happens. Could it be because the coat is hollow and theres a vertex hidden in the inside somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This vertex is not assigned to the right vertex group, you need to parent again, but first recalculate the normal because they are currently flipped (in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: Recalculate for the coat? Or for the armature?

Comment: Recalculate the coat mesh